# css transitions on flex-basis not working in FF

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, flexbox

When using CSS transitions and flex-basis on Firefox (28 as of this writing), the very first transition fails to smoothly progress. Subsequent transitions however are smooth as expected.

Here is a good demo of the issue I'm referring to:
http://dev.opera.com/static/articles/2013/animating-flexboxes/flexbox-transition-js/flexbox-transition-javascript.html

Is there something wrong with the logic of the code that trips FF up, or should this be filed as a bug perhaps? I've exhausted my knowledge base trying to solve this one.

My findings on other Browsers:

- Chrome: Works as expected on all transitions.
- FireFox: Initial transition fails, subsequent transitions work fine.
- IE11: All transitions fail, doesn't appear to support transitions on flex-basis.

Thanks,

UPDATE 1:
Mozilla created: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989075

Comment: i see no failure in FF28 win7

Comment: I can sporadically reproduce the failure. (After poking around in dev tools, it seems to go away, and then stays fixed, even after reloads.)  I'm using Firefox nightly on Linux.  In any case, definitely seems like a bug; can you file one at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Layout and CC me (:dholbert)?

Comment: Yes I too am on Linux, so perhaps this is an isolated issue. I fired up a Win7 VM and was not able to repo. I believe F12 is triggering a reflow/repaint which masks the issue.