# flexbox animation keyframes on Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, flexbox

Why flex keyframes doesn't work in Safari? In other browsers, all works fine.

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

.a {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex:0 1 50%;  
  border: 20px solid red;
  animation: anim-b 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim-b {
    0% { flex:0 1 0%; }
    100% { flex:0 1 100%; }
}
```

Comment: maybe a bug, as you can see here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695915/css-transitions-on-flex-basis-not-working-in-ff

Comment: @TemaniAfif That post is a little old, talks mostly about FF and where about `transition`, not `animation`.

Comment: @LGSon yes i know it's old but i think this seems to be more a bug (as this old post) than an issue so i pointed this link as a simple example so he can search this way, because transtion or animation behave the same i guess.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is a bug...updated my answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Btw, `transition` and `animation` might _behave_ similar, though are two different properties, where one can have a buggy behavior for a certain property it effects, and the other work perfectly fine. If you try using `flex-basis` with `transition` you'll see it works.

Comment: @LGSon yes you are right, i think they share a lot of similar behavior like the way some calculation are done by the browser but since they are different for sure there is some small *hidden* things that are not the same  and it seems Safari failed on one of these small things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animations can be picky (buggy) when one mix longhand and shorthand properties.

In this case Safari also has a bug when animating `flex-basis`, which I just noticed is still not fixed in ver. 11.

- https://github.com/DrummerHead/safari-flex-basis-animation-bug

In this case, for the default `row` direction, you need to use `width` instead.

Stack snippet

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex:0 1 auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 20px solid red;
  animation: anim-b 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim-b {
    0% { width: 0%; }
    100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```